# What makes a good physics/engineering poster?

Tags: conference, presentation, physics, engineering, poster

A more general form of this question has been answered [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/what-are-some-general-good-principles-for-creating-a-poster-for-a-poster-session) for example, but I want to know what makes a good poster presentation in **physics** and/or **engineering** conferences.

Obviously the poster must be visually appealing as discussed in various posts here, but I have seen cases where the most stunning posters (looks really good and well-written) did not win poster prizes when judged by professors at the conferences. Can you give reasons as to why this happens? Are there some special conditions or requirements in physics/engineering for such presentations?

Comment: You say the "most stunning posters" did not win.. So, who chose these "most stunning posters"? If that is your opinion, you are entitled to it, but the judges made a collective decision based on their criteria not yours... The answers given seem relevant to all subjects...

Comment: The academics and organizers usually choose the winning poster. At one conference, many participants I spoke to noted that there was one or more "stunning posters" - these ultimately didn't win any prizes. My question is: what criteria (other than the poster itself) do academics look for when judging a poster? I should note that I have mostly attended conferences (with poster presentations) in the UK and EU.

Comment: “The judges made a collective decision based on their criteria” - untill you ask the judges exactly what they were looking for at each and every conference which could / will be different at each then you won’t know - anything else is just a guess

Comment: I don't believe that this is actually any different for physics and engineering than it is in general for scientific posters.

Comment: Some might suggest that a "good" poster and a "prize winning" poster, while not orthogonal, are not necessarily well correlated.